# Edit last row per group in data table conditionally

Tags: r, datatable

I have the following exemplary DT:

```
set.seed(42)
test <- data.table(group=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),matrix(rnorm(81),9,3))
test[,.SD[.N],by=group]
```

The last command shows the last row per group.

What I would like to do now, for example, is to calculate a new column with values just for the last row per group (otherwise NA). This column should test if V1 > V2 > V3, and if so, return 999, if V3 > V2 > V1, return 111, otherwise return NA.

I tried a couple of commands using the usual `:=` operator, but it doesn't seem to work on `.SD[.N]`. Is this possible in the current version of DT?

Thanks for any hints. Solution please in `datatable` if possible.

Comment: Does it need to be data.table solution?

Comment: @thc if possible yes. I am working with DT now. Otherwise I would have to switch just for this task.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be a `data.table` solution, you can do this:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(data.table)

set.seed(42)
test <- data.table(group=c(rep("A",3),
rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
matrix(rnorm(81),9,3))

test[,.SD[.N],by=group] %>% 
  mutate(newvalue = ifelse(V1 > V2 & V1 > V3, 999, 
                           ifelse(V3 > V2 & V3 > V1,
                                  111, NA)))
```

## Edit

Instead of using nested `ifelse`, you can use `dplyr::case_when`, which is more easy to read.

```
test[,.SD[.N],by=group] %>% 
  mutate(newvalue = 
           case_when(V1 > V2 & V1 > V3 ~ 999, 
                     V3 > V2 & V3 > V1 ~ 111))
```

Comment: @DJVJ thanks, do you know how to do this in datatable only? If not, is the above solution stable? If I see this correctly, you mix datatable and plyr in one command.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I'm not well familiar with the data.table package. However, the script did work for me and according to the data.table vignettes there shouldn't be any problem to mix packages: "Furthermore, data.table inherits from data.frame. It is a data.frame, too. A data.table can be passed to any package that only accepts data.frame and that package can use [.data.frame syntax on the data.table" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html). Regardless, always do sanity checks to your script ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the reply. I will wait a bit more if someone has a more datatablish solution, as I'd prefer to stick to one package though.